# apache drill on cluster start error

Tags: apache-drill

I install apache drill on a cluster with 3 nodes.
When I use the following command to start it,it will not really running.

`bin/drillbit.sh start`

error

[image]

I don't know how to solve it and want you help.

The zookeeper is running without problems.

Then I check the log, and it show the following infos:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failure while initializing values in Drillbit.
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:287)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:271)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:267)

Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Problem in finding the native library of JPAM (Pluggable Authenticator Module API). Make sure to set Drillbit JVM option 'java.library.path' to point to the directory where the native JPAM exists.:no jpam in java.library.path
```

I check the java.library.path, it is the following:

```
/home/hadoop/bigdata/hadoop-2.7.2/lib/native/::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

So, I add the following setting:

```
declare -x DRILL_JAVA_LIB_PATH="/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib"
```

However, it not work and turn out the same problem like before.

Comment: Please include the text of the error messages in the body of the question and do not include a screen image of plain text.  All else apart, the image is nearly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The `declare -x DRILL_JAVA_LIB_PATH` snippet you provided will not point drill to the pam library. Please follow all the instructions in the Drill docs here https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jpam-as-the-pam-authenticator/

**Note:** you will have to perform those steps on all 3 nodes of your cluster.